# Can we keep creating Azure Shared Access Signatures on demand, server-side?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, token

We plan on uploading files to an Azure blob. By default, uploading anything to an Azure blob will be private. As in, the Uri for that blob item can only be accessed if they person is auth'd.

We plan on listing all the files, people upload to this single container. We plan on displaying this on a webpage.

We thought we could list all of these Uri's on a webpage and **include in the Uri an SaS value in the Uri**.

So then we thought: how do we generate short lived SaS's?

So

- can we keep creating SaS's on demand?
- Is there a limit (per container)?

(side note: I was thinking of having a static SaS token that hasn't expired and using it, else generate a new one. Expiry is like 15 mins or something).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can continue to create them and there is no limit. SAS tokens are not tracked by Azure Storage, they are generated by the client and signed with a signature that the Azure Storage endpoint uses to verify it's validity.

From the docs (emphasis my own):

> Note that the **SAS token is a string generated on the client side** (see the SAS examples section below for code examples). The SAS token generated by the storage client library **is not tracked by Azure Storage in any way**. **You can create an unlimited number of SAS tokens** on the client side.
>
> When a client provides a SAS URI to Azure Storage as part of a request, the service checks the SAS parameters and signature to verify that it is valid for authenticating the request. If the service verifies that the signature is valid, then the request is authenticated. Otherwise, the request is declined with error code 403 (Forbidden).

-- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1

Comment: Ah!!! i get it now :) it's the signature hash that is checked against the provided params (expiry, https only, etc) ... and trying to guess that signature is .. well .. good luck!